# How to open a new html page and also a link at one button click

Tags: javascript, html

So, what I want to do is open a URL that I am providing in `href` and at the same time open a new html page. On button click it leads to the URL in a new window with `target="_blank"`. But what I want to do is open the link in the new window and also open a new HTML page in the previous window.

Below is my code,

```
<li class="search-li">
    <div class="collapsible-header collapsible-noborder sakura-lighter-bg">
        <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>TEST LIST
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body collapsible-noborder sakura-midlight-bg">
        <button class="primary download">
            <a id="buttton1" class="buttton7" target="_blank" href="example.com">Download</a>
        </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It's better to avoid nesting interactive elements, like link inside button and vice versa. Besides being invalid HTML, such code can confuse browsers which element's action should trigger first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

[Test page](http://plungjan.name/SO/testclickopen.html)

The click will open a new window with the data-href and change existing window with href

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.open(this.getAttribute("data-href"), "_blank")
  })
})
```

```html
<li class="search-li">
  <div class="collapsible-header collapsible-noborder sakura-lighter-bg">
    <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>TEST LIST
  </div>
  <div class="collapsible-body collapsible-noborder sakura-midlight-bg">
    <a id="button1" class="primary download button7" 
     data-href="https://example1.com" 
          href="https://example2.com">Download</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Adding an event listener at loading and click could be avoided, see my answer below

Comment: @MaximeHelen It could but should not. See the overall opinion in development on inline event handling.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use window.open() method.

```html
<li class="search-li">
<div class="collapsible-header collapsible-noborder sakura-lighter-bg">
    <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>TEST LIST
</div>
<div class="collapsible-body collapsible-noborder sakura-midlight-bg">
    <button  class="primary download">
        <a   onclick="window.open('http://google.com');"  id="buttton1" class="buttton7"   href="https://www.w3schools.com"  >Download</a>
    </button>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: This will not open two windows. Just FYI.

Comment: You'll need to use window.location.href = ""; or window.location.replace(""); to redirect the original page.  Though, you may have issues if you have cross https/http sites as a security precaution.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Open two windows? I don't see that need anywhere

Comment: @MaximeHelen  OP question - `On button click it leads to the URL in a new window with target="_blank". But what I want to do is open the link in the new window and also open a new HTML page in the previous window.` - Also the answer was edited when after i posted the comment. Looks fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Below should do the job:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://google.com');" id="buttton1" 
     class="buttton7" href="http://yahoo.com">Download</a>
```

No need of `_blank` since `window.open()` does that for us, while the current window updates its location from `href` attribute

Comment: It is not recommended to have inline event handling, regardless how many bytes of code it would save.

Comment: @mplungjan Not recommended because an eval is processed against the href and the native function is evil sure. But here the code to execute is hardcoded so w/e

Comment: Not recommended due to separation of markup and code - unobtrusiveness

Comment: Ah React or Vue made me forget this guideline

Answer (score 1):

You can use This

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='page2.html'">Go to another page in your folder</button>
```

or you can use a link like that

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://example.com/'">Go to another page in an URL</button>
```

Comment: This is not answering the question. It is not opening a new page AND changing existing page

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<li class="search-li">
    <div class="collapsible-header collapsible-noborder sakura-lighter-bg">
        <i class="fa fa-mobile-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>TEST LIST
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body collapsible-noborder sakura-midlight-bg">
        <button class="primary download">
            <a id="buttton1" onmouseup="window.location.replace('/blank.html');" class="buttton7" target="_blank" href="example.com">Download</a>
        </button>
    </div>
</li>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why on earth using onmouseup instead of click? Also OP did not ask for a replace of current page

Comment: @mplungjan , onmouseup event will trigger after anchor tag click event happen,... so we can get two links... href in new tab as well as replace link open in same tab.

Comment: onclick is the same - exactly the same effect - also there is no onmouseup on  a mobile for example

Comment: @mplungjan, Yeah you are right, For mobile can include pointerup event.

Comment: Or just use onclick which is mapped to touchstart

Comment: @mplungjan , but when use onclick with window.location, then href link won't load.

Comment: window.open works just fine in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, IE11, iOS Safari
http://plungjan.name/SO/testclickopen.html